# Finding lines with extreme values using SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, sas, proc-sql

I have  a table, t1, with 4 columns:

```
key, cd, date, result_num
```

In SAS we have the following code:

```
PROC SQL;
    create table t2 AS
    select * from t1
    group by key
    having date = MAX(date)
    order by key, cd;
RUN;
```

I was under the impression that all columns that are being selected when using an aggregate function, such as MAX, had to be either in the group by or have an aggregate function applied to them. My goal is to convert this SAS code to SQL, is there a way to do this in SQL (hiveQL more specifically)?

Comment: This "SAS code" is already SQL, because it is inside a `PROC SQL`. You did however forget a semicolon after the order clause. What are you actually trying?

Comment: Sorry, fixed that typo. I didn't write this code, but assume it is taking the rows where the date is max for each key. @DirkHorsten

Comment: Regarding: *I was under the impression that all columns that are being selected when using an aggregate function, such as MAX, had to be either in the group by or have an aggregate function applied to them. *The SAS implementation of SQL allows the selection of other variables and merges the results back in. This can be a very useful feature or undesired depending on the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to access your input table twice: once to calculate the maximal date and once to select the appropriate data

If you look for the rows fro which the date is the highest date occurring in the whole table, that is

```
PROC SQL;
    create table t2 AS
    select * from t1
    where date = (select MAX(date) from t1)
    order by key, cd;
RUN;
```

If you look for the rows fro which the date is the highest date for thet same key, that is

```
PROC SQL;
    create table t2 AS
    select * from t1 inner join 
    (  select MAX(date) as maxDate 
       from t1  
       group by key) as m1 
       on m1.key = t1.key and m1.maxDate = t1.date
    order by key, cd;
RUN;
```

Comment: In the SAS code in the OP, I'm not sure if it is selecting all rows where the date is equal to max(date) for a given key, or if it is only selecting one row. Grouping by key would imply that your result set would contain only distinct keys, right? What would happen if there were 2 rows where key and date were duplicates, and date also happened to be max(date)? @DirkHorsten

Comment: The original SAS code had no logic to remove duplicate observations. So if there are ties for MAX(date) for a particular value of KEY then all such observations would be selected.

Comment: Try `select distinct`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your query is doing what you want in SAS . . . perhaps it does.  In standard SQL (and Hive) you can do:

```
create table t2 AS
    select *
    from (select t1.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by key order by date desc) as seqnum
          from t1
         ) t1
    where seqnum = 1
    order by key, cd;
```

Comment: Did you forget to remove a semicolon after adding the order clause?

Comment: Wouldn't this only select one row? Whereas in the OP multiple rows could be selected if they both contained the MAX(date)? @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Danzo . . . If you want duplicates, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.  Usually the intention of such logic is to get one row per group, but you are correct in your observation.  In most databases, I would expect this to be faster than a version using a subquery.

Comment: Your query is attempting to return only one observation when there are ties, which is a different query than the original code.  The original code works in SAS, but in other implementations of SAS it might be invalid since it selects variables that are neither part of the GROUP BY list or aggregate statistics. But SAS allows such queries.

Comment: @Tom . . . I have no idea what your point is.  As mentioned, if you want ties, use `rank()`.  There is no `group by`, so the rest of your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - In SAS (ie the actual original code) there is a GROUP BY. In your code the "new fangled" (less than 20 years old) concept of PARTITION BY is doing the "grouping".  I was surprised to hear that a modern SQL implementation couldn't optimize what are essentially the same query.  I would expect that calculating RANK() would be harder than calculating MAX(), at least taking more working memory.